# Saving to a different folder in ZIP

Tags: zip

```
zip compress.zip /from/this/path/settings.json
```

I have the command above, but would like to store in `/path/settings.json` instead of `/from/this/path/settings.json` in the zip file.

How do I go about it?

Comment: 1. Is it enough with a method that works for a single file or do you need a method, that works for a whole directory tree with several directories and subdirectories with files? 2. Would it be OK to use a method with some other tool(s), for example `gzip` (and `tar` if a whole directory tree)?

Comment: actually i found a "workaround", change working directory to `/from/this` and zip from there. But to answer your qn: 1. I would say multiple files, because I'm after the folders, although there is only 1 file now. 2. preferably not, I mean, I just want it to be an easy to read 1 liner.

Comment: Your workaround is good :-) It is possible to use a oneliner (or corresponding alias) also with `tar` (and let it use compression with `gzip`: `tar -cvzf ball.tar.gz directory-tree` or `xz`: `tar -cvJf ball.tar.xz directory-tree`)